# Trying to update / upsert from one class to another

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

The following can be used to create the scenario

```
CREATE CLASS v1 EXTENDS v
CREATE CLASS v2 EXTENDS v
CREATE PROPERTY v1.p1 STRING 
CREATE PROPERTY v1.p2 STRING 
CREATE PROPERTY v1.p3 STRING 
CREATE PROPERTY v2.p1 STRING (MANDATORY TRUE)
CREATE PROPERTY v2.p2 STRING (MANDATORY TRUE)
CREATE PROPERTY v2.p3 STRING 
CREATE INDEX v2.p1 UNIQUE
INSERT INTO v1 (p1,p2,p3) VALUES ('a','b','c')
INSERT INTO v1 (p1,p2,p3) VALUES ('d','e','f')
INSERT INTO v1 (p1,p2,p3) VALUES ('h','i','j')
INSERT INTO v2 (p1,p2,p3) VALUES ('a','y','z')
```

and these are the results of the following select queries

select from v1

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#33:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "v1",
            "p1": "a",
            "p2": "b",
            "p3": "c"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#34:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "v1",
            "p1": "d",
            "p2": "e",
            "p3": "f"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#35:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "v1",
            "p1": "h",
            "p2": "i",
            "p3": "j"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed  in 0.011 sec. Returned 3 record(s)"
}
```

select from v2

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#41:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "v2",
            "p1": "a",
            "p2": "y",
            "p3": "z"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed  in 0.013 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

I have tried multiple sql statements to try to merge the fields from v1 to v2 and hunted google for nearly two days now but cant find an answer. Can you advise where I am going wrong

```
LET $t = SELECT FROM v1
UPDATE v2 SET (p1,p2) VALUES ($t.$current.p1, $t.$current.p2) UPSERT WHERE $current.p1 = $t.$current.p1
```

Desired result would be to update the current record in v2 to have values ‘a, b, z’ and have the additional two records added as they are in v1

Comment: so, just to clarify, you want to have, at the end, v2 containing "a b v" "d e" "h i"?

Comment: v2 needs to contain 3 records

Comment: v2 needs to contain 3 records. record 1 (a,b,z), record 2 (d,e,f), record 3 (h,i,j)

Comment: record 1 that already exists in v2 just has the p1 and p2 properties updated and record 2 and 3 are created new because the v2 index on the p1 property is not found.

Comment: ok, I dont think that's possibile using simple query. maybe with a js function

Comment: the rule I am trying to apply is. For each record in v1 if the property p1 matches the index p1 in v2 then I want to update the p2 property in v2. If the p1 property in the record in v1 can not be matched to the index in v2 then I want a new record created in v2

Comment: I thought I might be able to do it with an insert and an update but I have tried all sorts of combinations with no luck. Any idea what the outline of the js function would need to look like, would it need to make a call to the database with a connection each time it ran?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a javascript function to do it.

**Initial scenario:**
[image]

**JS Function:**

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
var v1 = g.command("sql","SELECT FROM v1");

for(i=0; i<v1.length; i++){
  var check_index = g.command("sql","select from index:v2.p1 where key='"+v1[i].getProperty("p1")+"'");
  if(check_index.length>0){
    //v1 record already present in v2 index - UPDATE
    print("#### "+"update "+check_index[0].getProperty("rid").getId()+" set p2='"+v1[i].getProperty("p2")+"'"+" ####");
    g.command("sql","update "+check_index[0].getProperty("rid").getId()+" set p2='"+v1[i].getProperty("p2")+"'");
  } else {
    //v1 record not present in v2 index - INSERT
    print("#### "+"insert into v2 set p1='"+v1[i].getProperty("p1")+"',p2='"+v1[i].getProperty("p2")+"',p3='"+v1[i].getProperty("p3")+"'"+" ####");
    g.command("sql","insert into v2 set p1='"+v1[i].getProperty("p1")+"',p2='"+v1[i].getProperty("p2")+"',p3='"+v1[i].getProperty("p3")+"'");
  }
  g.commit();
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: sorry, been away for a couple of days, will give this a try

Comment: Hi @JohnBrogan if this is useful for you, could you mark the answer as correct? Thank you very much :-)